# nextauth can't get jwt token, not hitting the breakpoint

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, next-auth

I'm trying to access firebase auth token from google login, and call another API from SSR. The jwt token in `[...next-auth]` never gets hit in debug mode. As a result, ssr, shows blank token.

signin page uses `next-auth/react`

`import { signIn, getCsrfToken, getProviders, useSession } from 'next-auth/react'`

What did I miss here?

This is my `[...next-auath]`:

```
export default NextAuth({
  // https://next-auth.js.org/providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
      idToken: true,
      checks: ["pkce", "state"],
      async profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.name,
          email: profile.email,
          email_verified: profile.email_verified
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
    signOut: '/auth/signout',
    error: '/auth/error'
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET,
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
  }),
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ account, profile }) {
      if (account.provider === "google") {
        return profile.email_verified 
      }
      return false
    },
    jwt: async({ token, user, account }) => {
      ////////////////// Never reaches here
      if (account && user) {
        return {
          accessToken: account.access_token,
          accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + account.expires_in * 1000,
          refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
          user
        }
      }
      if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires) {
        return token
      }
      return refreshAccessToken(token)
    },
    session: async (session, user) => {
      //////// OK, comes here
      return Promise.resolve(session);
    },
  },
```